# Automatically Backup Database using PHP when client enters and if backup does not exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do have a idea to backup a client's Database using PHP.
It is a website of product management and I would like to backup it monthly.

Instead of doing an Window Schedule Task that would to a SQL dump on the wanted database wouldn't be brilliant to automatically do this when users log-in.

**The plan is this**: On every user login, check somehow if backup on the current month already exists, if it does not exists, it automatically makes a sql-dump and moves the backup.zip into a secure folder on the server.
The point is that every day a user will login.

Is this a good plan? Would it have any disadvantages over an manually backup or something? Performance loss over the .zip check ?

Comment: backups for big databases take some (long) time, but use exec to run mysqldump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a horrible plan. It is just adding complexity for no reason. Let's break down the problems you will need to solve with this approach.

- The backup action cannot slow down the request. This means you will need to introduce a full on queuing server
- Have some way of tracking if the backup already happened. This means you will either have to add another table in your database. This will introduce duplicate information. Another way will be to mount the file system and check the file date. This is a lot of extra code and or library dependencies.
- You say every day a user will log in. Is this true during the weekends?

If you decide to go this route, you will in essence couple the server management with the application logic. This is just unnecessary. It is complex, error prone and most importantly, a lot harder to set up on a dev machine now.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, so what would be an alternative of what I would like to accomplish ?

Comment: could you please describe the queuing server a little bit more ? 
because for the tracking i would just check if file with date exists, and yes there would be users on the weekend.

Comment: This is administration stuff. Use the tools in your OS. I don't know how the scheduler in windows works, but if you have Unix you can use cron. Simply create a script that makes a dump of the server, zips it and sends it off to the relevant places. Then use the scheduler to automatically call the script at whatever interval you see fit

Comment: A queuing server is a server that receives messages and only acts on them when it has the time. This is needed for your login solution as database backups can take a very long time. Instead of doing that during the login request (which will then take ages), you simply send a message to the queuing server to do it, which will do it as soon as possible without slowing the system down.